# Checking if some fields of an object are null

Tags: java, validation, legacy-code

i'm facing a problem with a wrong designed java Object with 34 parameters.

This object can sometime has 3 filled values and the others **must** be null .
In a second case 15 fields are filled, the others must be null etc...

I can't change this object now as it's linked to the repository model.

Is there a way to check if a list of field names are empty ?
I was also thinking of creating a sub-object to create an isEmpty() method in order to split the size of the check.

For example this class "Guy" :

```
public class Guy {
    private String name;
    private String haveCar;
    private String carBrand;
    private String isRentedCar;
    private String rentCarCompany;

    public checkGuy(Guy guy){
        if(guy.getHaveCar.equals("YES")){
            // check if car brand exist
            if ( guy.isRentedCar.equals("YES")){
                // check if rent car company in db ...
            }
        }
    }
    
    // ...
}
```

When someone POST this object, i want to avoid this object to be saved :

```json
"Guy": {
    "name": "guy",
    "haveCar": "NO",
    "carBrand": "Renault", // nonsense
    "isRentedCar":"NO",
    "rentCarCompany":"RentACarCompany" // nonsense
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, because I see this quite frequently: where did you learn that *JAVA* was an acronym? Because it's not: it's the name of an island, and thus spelled *Java*.

Comment: Make it impossible for outside code to create an invalid object.  You can use custom constructors, or make the constructors private and create static factory methods, or make the constructors private and create a builder class.  Of course, if the relevant properties have set-methods, you’ll want to add checks that can throw IllegalStateException, to keep the object valid at all times.

Comment: this object is the result of a POST deserializied with @RequestBody so i recieved it like that unfortunatly. I have to deals with all these null fields but if i check each one , one by one each time it will make a really big "if" statement

Comment: Just write a custom validator that counts the populated fields and fails if > 3 are populated. Could even go fancy and make it a custom annotation for your validation library of choice if this is a common pattern.

Comment: The number of populated fields depends of what is inside of some of them.
For exemple:
 if field 1 contains "Yes" then, fields 2,3,4 must be filled and others must be null.
if fields 2 containes "Yes" field 5 must be filled.

The final goal is to check if the object is well filled and can be saved in db.

I want to block someone who try to send fake object like :
field 1 is emplty and 2,3,4 are filled and it doesn't make sense

Comment: [*Jakarta Validation*](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/bean-validation/)

Answer (score 5):

This is a good question, because it happens a lot and a lot of people don't know how to deal with it.

Here's the question I think you're asking. We have a pre-existing class that we don't control.

```
public class TerribleClass {
  // Bad design choices live here :)
}
```

And we want *our* API to use this class intelligently. There's lots of footguns and ways to use the class badly that this poorly-written class *doesn't* help us deal with.

The answer, then, is to deal with `TerribleClass` as *little* as humanly possible. Your own code should deal with a wrapper class 99% of the time and only deal with `TerribleClass` when it absolutely has to.

```
public class GoodWrapper {
  private TerribleClass terribleObject;

  public GoodWrapper(TerribleClass terribleObject) {
    // Validate all preconditions here.
    if (terribleObject.isInvalidState()) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Found a terrible object in a bad state");
    }
    this.terribleObject = terribleObject;
  }

  // Now write getters for all of the data we can safely access.
  // We're doing it right this time, so make sure any functions that
  // can return null are documented as such. Consider using @Nullable
  // and @NotNull annotations. 

  public int getValueFromTerribleClass() {
    return terribleObject.whatever;
  }

}
```

Now you mention getting this from the network via a POST request. If your code currently looks something like

```
public TerribleClass makePostRequest(...) {
  TerribleClass result = RequestsLibrary.post(...);
  return result;
}
```

Now you write this instead.

```
public GoodWrapper makePostRequest(...) {
  TerribleClass result = RequestsLibrary.post(...);
  return new GoodWrapper(result);
}
```

The *only* function that has to deal with that messy, unchecked `TerribleClass` object is `makePostRequest`. *Everybody* who calls your function gets a nice friendly object whose invariants are checked.

The way to protect yourself and your downstream users from bad code is to insulate yourself from it. Class badly designed? Write a wrapper and only expose that. Are there API functions that return the bad class? Make an adaptor class that returns your nice instances. Make it so the all of your business logic sees the nice objects and, at worst, you have a few wrappers that have to make messy decisions. But all of the mess is centralized in one place.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I added some informations to my first post but indeed i think a wrapper can be a good idea to deal with it.